# Structures array in C

Tags: c

I am still learning C, despite some working programs, but now I came to structures and the pains started.
I have an already working program, in `XC8` under `MPLABX` (target is a `PIC18`), composed by a `Main.c`, an header and some additional .c files.
In the header I already have an array of structures (font descriptors), perfectly working.

Now, I want to add a new piece of code (dynamic menus) so I made an additional header file (struct.h) with the structure and array definition, plus a new C file (menus.c) that will handle the menus; both files are included in the main.c

When I started to write the menu's rows assignements I got the following errors:

> invalid dimension

and then

> missing basic type; int assumed

These are the (very simplified) pieces of offending codes:

STRUCT.h

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H
#define STRUCT_H

typedef struct Row
{
    char *label;
    int posX;
    int posY;
};

struct Row rows[20];

#endif  /* STRUCT_H */
```

MENUS.c

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H
#include  "struct.h"
#endif

rows[0].posX = 1;
```

The error rises at this last row.
I'm 100% sure this is a mine very stupid error, but where?
Thanks

Comment: `rows[0].posX = 1;` should be in some function.

Comment: `typedef struct Row`...to?

Comment: "These are the (very simplified) pieces of offending codes" Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 1) You don't need `#ifndef/#endif` in your .c files.  It's an [Include Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard), and it's meant for .h header files. 2) It's OK to "declare" a variable in your header (e.g. `extern struct Rows *rows`), but you should "define" it in a .c file: http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's not necessary to protect the include from main since it's already done from STRUCT.h

So instead of in main

```
#ifndef STRUCT_H
#include  "struct.h"
#endif
```

directly use(in main the .h is the one which should have protection which it already does, no need to do it twice)

```
#include  "struct.h"
```

Now back to your code the problem you are having is that you're not modifying the structure in a function, meaning that rows[0].posX = 1; will never be executed

This should work:

```
#include "struct.h"

int main(void)
{

    rows[0].posX = 1;

    //do something else like print result etc
    return 0;
}
```

Also you're not using the typedef, it's an empty use of typedef since you didn't put any name afterwords  note these two are the same:

```
typedef struct Row
{
    char *label;
    int posX;
    int posY;
};



struct Row
{
    char *label;
    int posX;
    int posY;
};
```

I would use something along the lines of

```
typedef struct Row
{
    char *label;
    int posX;
    int posY;
}row_t;
```

Now you can directly use row_t as a data type instead of struct row

Finally I wouldn't make it a global variable I would make it local to main and pass a pointer to any function that requieres the array/membery of array

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Row
{
    char *label;
    int posX;
    int posY;
}row_t;


int main(void)
{

    row_t rows[20];//Not global local to main
    rows[0].posX = 1;
    printf("%d\n",rows[0].posX );
    //do something else like print result etc
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **note:** `typedef struct { ... } Row;` is all that is needed. He just had `Row` *before* rather than *after* the struct definition. Nothing wrong with `Row { ... } row_t;` syntax, but note it could as easily have been `Row { ... } Row;` and not provided any conflict.

Comment: The stupid error was I tried to assign values outside any function. Wrapping the assignement line in a function fixed the error. I took also note of the others suggestion.

Comment: Great to know it helped and although what @DavidC.Rankin is completely correct I personally prefer to end typedefs with _t. A practice which is seen frequently ex: size_t uint16_t ,etc